# Unable to change screen brightness with hotkeys on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: brightness, 14.10

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10, and now my brightness keys aren't working. Is there a fix for this? I suspect that Linux kernel 3.16 is the culprit...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For me it helped to remove a piece of the grub command line which was needed before in Ubuntu 14.04

From the grub file I removed a boot parameter as follow.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look up the line that looks more or less like this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

remove the text piece: acpi_osi=Linux
In my case the adjusted line is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

save file

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Brightness controls don't work in a fresh 14.10 install. Previously (14.04), the brightness controls worked fine.